# Zend method bool isHTTPS() check for SSL

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

Is there a method in ZF2 that returns wether the request is from within HTTPS ?

Like `$this->getRequest()->isHTTPS()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The check is:

```
$this->getRequest()->isSecure()
```

Comment: Might I ask you another question.. I need the full URL from the request but without the params, do you have a quick suggestion for that?

Comment: Zend_Uri_Http::fromString($url)

Comment: @DanFromGermany: Just saw the message. $this->getRequest()->getUriString() should serve the purpose as the documentation (http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.http.request.html) mentioned.

Comment: Thank you both for your response! I used this line now: `parse_url($request->getRequestUri(), PHP_URL_PATH)` because I need the UriString without parameters. Thanks again